# Translation for "everyone's"/"everybody's"

Tags: перевод, одним-словом

I can't seem to find a translation for "everyone's" as in "They took everyone's phones." Is there a word for this?

Answer (score 6):

We usually translate "everyone/everybody " either "все" or "каждый" meaning the whole group or each person separately.

> Телефоны отобрали у всех.
>
> Каждому дали книгу.

Comment: So there is no single word for the possessive "everyone's" (as in "everyone's car")?

Comment: @casey don't you think there is a conflict of concepts here? "everyone's car" is a single car shared by many (town's bicycle). "everyones' phones" are many phones, each one exclusively owned by somebody.
Those are different ideas, and I think they are conveyed differently in Russian.

Comment: @Arioch "Everyone's cars" and "everyone's car" mean the same thing to me (not one car, but many). My question was whether or not there was a single word for them. I know that чей-нибудь is "anyone's" so I was wondering if there was an analog to that.

Comment: There is also "no one's" - ничей. There is also "общий" - "common", (like public, shared thing).  /// "That everyone's car standing by that tree" ?

Comment: See, so you say that singular "car" becomes plural "cars" when some certain singular pronoun "everyone's" added... Look, I combine a singular noun with a singular pronoun and in the end I end with a plural noun in essence? This sounds very exotic idea to me, so I think this use of pronouns is exotic thing, specific to English (or maybe all Germanic languages)? I guess in Russian the singular "phone" would not be plural. Uncountable maybe (designated the whole class/concept/category of phones - like "Phone invention changed the world"), but not plural specific real objects.

Comment: "They took our phones"/"Our phones were taken" - "Наши телефоны забрали" is perhaps the closes form to what you ask.

Comment: Everyone's car (машина каждого была украшена флажками), каждого stands for каждого человека. But each time the translation might be different.  Our children trying to invent a universal pronoun, say "всехние", but that's ungrammatical.

Answer (score 4):

You don't use possessives in Russian the same way as you do in English. We often express possession by using the genitive case:

> teacher's book = книга учителя
>   John's car = машина Джона

Depending on the context, you can sometimes say "телефон каждого (человека)" to mean "everyone's phone". For example,

> Телефон каждого (человека) может быть прослушан. = Everyone's phone
>   can be bugged.

But Russian doesn't use possessives as much as English. For example, you normally say "Я почистил зубы" (= I brushed **my** teeth.), and **not** "Я почистил <strike>мои/свои</strike> зубы."

You often use the structure "*у меня/у тебя/у него* etc." instead of possessive pronouns in Russian:

> **У меня** болит шея. = **My** neck hurts.
>   **У неё** сломалась машина. = **Her** car broke down.
>   **У него** украли бумажник. = **His** wallet got stolen.
>   **У меня** зазвонил телефон. = **My** phone started ringing.
>   They took **everyone's** phones. = (Они) **у всех** забрали телефоны.